# Gameboy Key Input Causes Crash

Tags: hardware, programming, c, game-boy, joystick

I made a Key Tester using the **STDIO header** included with **GBDK**. It works... Until it *doesn't*. All the keys register and print to the screen, except the **Left**(5) and **Right**(4) **Directional Keys**, which cause the program to crash and the screen to go blank.

Pressing Left shows me this line in the Debugger **(BGB)**:

```
HRAM: FFAD D3                             undefined code                                     ;0 26
```

Pressing Right shows me this:

```
HRAM: FF00 10 10                          <corrupted stop>                                ;1 2
HRAM: FF82 B7                              or      a                                               ;0 26
```

And this line in the bottom right:

```
WRA1:DFAB 00A7
```

I've gone over countless documents to no avail, with no real answers as to why 6 out of 8 Gameboy keypresses register as expected.

Here is my code.

```
#include "C:\GBDK\include\stdio.h"
#include "C:\GBDK\include\gb\gb.h"

#define JOYPAD_REGISTER (*(volatile unsigned char *)0xFF00)
#define BUTTON_DOWN_REGISTER (*(volatile unsigned char *)0xFF80)
#define BUTTON_HIT_REGISTER (*(volatile unsigned char *)0xFF81)

void ReadJoypad() {
    unsigned char currentButtonState = 0;
    unsigned char previousButtonState, buttonHitState;
    
     //Directional Key Detection
    JOYPAD_REGISTER = 1 << 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        currentButtonState = JOYPAD_REGISTER;
    }
    currentButtonState = (~currentButtonState & 0x0F) << 4;

    JOYPAD_REGISTER = 1 << 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        currentButtonState |= ~JOYPAD_REGISTER & 0x0F;
    }

    previousButtonState = BUTTON_DOWN_REGISTER;
    buttonHitState = (previousButtonState ^ currentButtonState) & currentButtonState;
    BUTTON_HIT_REGISTER = buttonHitState;

    BUTTON_DOWN_REGISTER = currentButtonState;

    JOYPAD_REGISTER = 1 << 5 | 1 << 4;
}

void main() {
    while (1) {
        ReadJoypad();
        unsigned char buttonHitState = BUTTON_HIT_REGISTER;

        if (buttonHitState != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                if (buttonHitState & (1 << i)) {
                    printf("Button %d is being pressed\n", i);
                }
            }
        }
        delay(100);
    }
}
```

The first loop in `ReadJoypad()` is supposed to shift the **1 bit** of `0xFF00` left five times and then poll for presses on the D-Pad. That section of code seems to be where all my problems are coming from. And I've tried countless `printf()` tests to see what might be going wrong from the point of initialization onward. Nothing...

The only function sourced from `GB.h` is `delay()`

Comment: The macro definitions make me anxious: `*(volatile unsigned char *)0xFF00`. I would have written those like `(*(volatile unsigned char *)0xFF00)`, to make sure there were no surprises with how that macros combine with surrounding code.

Comment: Oh, wow. How did I miss that?! Swear... if that's all it takes...

Comment: Well, now the left (5) directional key works... still leaves the mystery of key 4...

Comment: No, nevermind... Back to square 0

Comment: What is the logic in not using variables for BUTTON_DOWN_REGISTER and BUTTON_HIT_REGISTER?

Comment: @UncleBod I'd imagine because Memory Addressing was the efficient choice.
https://github.com/alexsteb/tetris_disassembly/blob/master/constants.asm

Comment: @OPMeStudio Where do you think static variables are kept?

Comment: This issue doesn't involve static variables...

Comment: A variable with such an address is static. -- You cannot conclude from a disassembly that static variables are explicitly allocated at that address, and that _you_ can use the very same address with any other program.

Comment: I'm not assuming anything. I'm learning by example. The example didn't work, so I came here to learn why.

Comment: @OPMeStudio Don't allocate variables yourself into seemingly random addresses. You don't usually have to do that even in modern embedded systems, and if you do have to do it, you have to be able to find a good reason for it. Anyway, you could not have known how the C runtime sets up the software platform up. Then again, this is a modern C compiler with active developement and support forums and documentation available, even all the source codes used to target the retro platforms. So it's not about retro hardware or how to use it, but how to use a non-retro C compiler.

Comment: @OPMeStudio “This issue doesn't involve static variables...” – Exactly! Why? That’s what you would use in a normal C program, and you had no reason not to use them.

Comment: @Justme I definitely didn't come at this considering what the library and compiler were doing under the hood, but now that I know, I will be looking into it more. Thank you.

Comment: If you would use "normal" way of declaring hram for gameboy in sdcc you prolly would get warning from linker... "normal" way is `volatile __sfr __at (0xFFxx) variable_name;`

Comment: I think I'll pass, but thanks...

Comment: Also maybe matter of taste but instead of `unsigned char` you can include stdint.h and use `uint8_t` (not related to the problem)

Comment: Also do you know that there is [`joypad()`](https://gbdk-2020.github.io/gbdk-2020/docs/api/gb_8h.html#a4344fefd260763e12703138066841b19) function in gbdk already and [discord channel](https://github.com/gbdk-2020/gbdk-2020/#discord-servers)

Comment: Yes, but I'm not learning GBDK. I'm simply using its compiler to learn the Gameboy.

Comment: The solution should be posted as an answer, and **not** in the question, as [your last few edits](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/revisions/28337/6) have done. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was that the default address set for GBDK's OAM refresh function was **0xFF80** which conflicted with code.

Luckily, GBDK offers a solution via LCC during the linker phase:

```
lcc -Wl-g_refresh_OAM=0xFEFF -o  test.gb main.o
```

This allowed me to change the address used by refresh_OAM to **0xFEFF**. Which is commonly used for OAM manipulation in commercial titles.

Now, everything is in working order.

Thank you for all the answers and comments leading me to this answer.

```
// 0x0000 - 0x3FFF ROM 00
// 0x4000 - 0x7FFF ROM 01+
// 0x8000 - 0x9FFF VRAM
// 0xA000 - 0xBFFF ExRAM
// 0xC000 - 0xDFFF WRAM
// 0xE000 - 0xFDFF Echo RAM
// 0xFE00 - 0xFEFF OAM
// 0xFF00 - 0xF7FF HARDWARE
// 0xFF80 - 0xFFFE HRAM
// 0xFFFF Interrupt Switch
```

> **Please Note:** I'm only using GBDK as a bootstrap with the goal of abandoning it entirely. Apart from dealing with the library's defaults in with regards to this code, this post in general does not pertain to GBDK.

Comment: This cannot be a solution. Why tell the linker to copy the refresh_OAM code to **FEFF**? The first byte of code goes to area that is marked "Not Usable"/"Prohibited" as using that area is unstable and may trigger OAM corruption in some HW platforms. And the next bytes will overwrite the IO registers. The solution is to either move it to some area that works, or force your variables to use area that is free, or better and simplest solution what you should be doing in the first place, let the compiler decide where to put the variable like in any normal C program.

Comment: Whom are you quoting?

Comment: @user3840170 Not any specific source, but if you take any source describing the memory map of the device, those kind of words are used for FEA0-FEFF area.

Comment: @user3840170, stop changing the name of my post. GBDK uses FF80 for OAM refresh. Not every one does. Not knowing this caused a conflict, because my code and their code were interfering with one another. The goal is to nix GBDK from my workflow, so your title doesn't fit the issue. Whether or not my current fix will be my permanent fix is to be seen, but the issue isn't hardware, or me using that hardware incorrectly. Its two developers fighting over the same resource.

Answer (score 15):

The modern compiler, or rather, the underlying libraries and build system that come with the compiling environment put some important code and/or data in the addresses FF80 and FF81 which you happily overwrite.

It seems that there is a function called `refresh_OAM` and it is called periodically in vblank interrupt, and the code of this function is copied to HRAM address FF80 by default in the platform specific C startup code.

So do not use hard coded memory addresses unless you know from the docs that the addresses are free.

Comment: Those two addresses are used for both BUTTON_DOWN and BUTTON_HIT in the GB assembly for Tetris. So, it seemed reasonable to use the same addresses when writing my Key Tester in C.

Comment: @OPMeStudio Each compiled program (for such a system) has static variables allocated to certain addresses. But it is an error to use the very same address for other programs.

Comment: Of course, but when you're starting your experimentation from null, all you have are the examples and documentation available to you. I'll get it eventually.

Comment: Ah, I was just assuming those were some memory mapped IO addresses from the gameboy hardware or something.

Comment: @JonHess No you were on the right track. FF00 is the IO address for the joypad keys. FF80 and FF81 are addresses in HRAM. But apparently, the GBDK uses them for the OAM...

Comment: Well for function which copy shadow_oam to oam... It have to be in hram - that's how DMA works on gameboy... You can disable it with `DISABLE_OAM_DMA;` (but than most sprites related function in gbdk are useless)

Comment: That's good to know.